# How does Objective-C provide a dynamic runtime?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, binding

How does Objective-C provide a "dynamic" runtime?  What does "dynamic" refer to here?

Comment: @PratyushaTerli 1: Objective-C makes heavy use of PODs, so not every element is an object. 2: Objects don't make a language dynamic, it's the functions/methods that operate on objects. Your description explains why Objective-C is called an "object oriented" language.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In one sentence: Objective-C decides which method *implementation* to call right before doing so (during runtime). The idea is that the connection between the *name* of a method and the *implementation* is dynamic. C++ for example resolves names during compile time.

Example:

```
id object = @"1";
int i = [object intValue];

object = @1;
i = [object intValue];
```

In this example the `intValue` message is first sent to an instance of `NSString` and then to an `NSNumber`. The code emitted by the compiler is identical for both calls–in fact the compiler does not even know to which kind of object it's sending messages to (as the type is `id`).

The runtime decides which implementation to call to extract an int value from a string or an `NSNumber`.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. Can you give me an example to this?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic term referes to the binding with the virtual tables.Also known as late binding, if the binding occurs at compile time, then it's not important what is the real object that receives the message, but the important is the type of reference to this object.With the late binding instead, the important is the object (and personally I prefer late binding), so when you override a method this will get called for sure if the object belongs to that class.Consider this class:

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@end


#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

- (NSString*) description
{
    return @"A good person, smart but lazy";
}

@end
```

If you try to log the description:

```
NSObject* obj=[[Person alloc]init];
NSLog(@"%@",obj); // same as NSLog(@"%@",[obj description]);
```

This logs "A good person, smart but lazy".If the binding with the virtual table was static, it was used the description method of the superclass NSObject, so you would see just the address of the object between braces:

```
<Person: 0x1001083b0>   // Address of the object
```

In C++ there is the static binding, very annoying to my personal opinion.Java and Objective-C are dynamic.