# What is the compiler doing when I set an object's delegate to "self" in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, compilation, delegates, swift3

In my code I have `UIViewController` that implements `UITextFieldDelegate`, and `UIPickerViewDelegate`.

The delegates for the `textField` and `pickerView` are assigned via `textField.delegate = self` and `pickerView.delegate = self` respectively.

I understand the protocols state for both only accept types that match their delegate, but I'm not sure how the compiler discerns between the two types of `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UITextFieldDelegate` as the class is both protocols could be passed through as self.

**What exactly is the compiler doing when I set** `textField.delegate` **and** `pickerView.delegate` **to** `self`**?**  It seems the compiler is smart enough to figure it out, but I'm curious to know what happens behind the scenes.

Ex:

```
class TextFieldViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,  UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerView.delegate = self
        textField.delegate = self
    }

}
```

Comment: There is nothing too smart there I guess. The only thing that matters is that the object which is set as `delegate` is implementing a specific protocol and compiler knows that from your class declaration

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean - the compiler parses through the code, notices the pickerView variable that's actually an instance of a UIPickerView, then it knows that a UIPickerView has an instance variable called delegate that is the type of UIPickerViewDelegate? and so it sets the delegate to self - which is an instance of some object that conforms to the UIPickerViewDelegate. Same goes for the UITextField

Comment: How does it know between all of the defined delegates? I know it's conforming to the protocol to find it, but how does that process work?

I apologize if this was a stupid question to ask.

Comment: @uti0mnia How does it notice the pickerView variable is actually an instance of a UIPickerView? I know I define it, but how does it check against that?

Comment: @JimmyHsu oh, so when the compiler does its first "pass" it records each variable and it's type. And in your case when you do "@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!" You're telling the compiler that it's a UIPickerView

Comment: @uti0mnia err, sorry I mean if `pickerView.delegate` is equal to a `UIPickerViewDelegate` which is differentiated by the compiler vs the other delegates. In a sense, how the compiler is able to know the difference between the listed delegate definitions and figure out how to determine `UIPickerViewDelegate` is indeed the right delegate. Sorry, with trying to figure out how to word this all this I'm starting to confuse myself now.

I've been told by a friend that this is more a question about compilers, so I added that tag. I'm realizing the question is more related to that than I thought.

Comment: @uti0mnia regardless, thanks for explain that part out though, helps me as I go through

Comment: @JimmyHsu ah, well, the instance variable delegate of the UIPickerView object (pickerView) is a UIPickerViewDelegate, does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What exactly is the compiler doing when I set textField.delegate

There are two answers to this question: one for pure Swift types and one for Objective-C protocols.

As your example is about Objective-C (because `UITextFieldDelegate` is an Objective-C protocol) I'm going to answer this one first.

#### Objective-C `@protocol`

The compiler's job is not only to produce code but also to check for correctness. It does so by making sure that the static type of the object assigned to a `UITextField`'s `delegate` property matches the declaration. In this case the compiler would complain if `self`'s type would not conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`.

This is called [static type safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) and is a pure compile time concept which does not affect code or runtime.

In a later stage the compiler has to produce code that performs the actual assignment. In case of setting an objc property it will look up the setter name (coming up with `setDelegate:`) and emit an `objc_msgSend` call with this selector.

The [magic in this function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13306198/104790) is what makes it possible to send arbitrary messages to any object. Because this happens during runtime (the term is "late binding", or "dynamic dispatch") the *compiler's* job is done at this point.

When the text field tries to callback to the delegate, it uses the same mechanism to send messages. It does not have to know anything about the type of the delegate, apart from that it's an Objective-C object.

This is true for both Objective-C and Swift code, when using `@objc` instances.

#### Pure Swift `protocol`

Everything changes when the delegate is a pure Swift protocol (not derived from the `NSObject` protocol). As your question is not specifically about this case I'm not going into too much detail.

In pure Swift there's no late binding: The connection between a name of a method and its implementation is made during compile time (while in Objective-C this happens during runtime).

As the delegate property in a hypothetical pure Swift `TextField` has to have a way to find protocol methods in the delegate, the compiler creates a so called witness table for the protocol and static type and stores that along with the instance. When calling a method in the delegate the compiler routes the call through the witness table to find the actual implementation. Much more work is done during compile time than in the Objective-C case.

If you want to know more about how Swift represents data and dispatches methods there's a [2016 WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/) which goes into some detail (and here's [the transcript](http://asciiwwdc.com/2016/sessions/416)).

Also, I very much recommend diving into the [Swift ABI documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI.rst). The section about [Existential Container Layout](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI.rst#existential-container-layout) describes how the pure Swift `TextField` would store its `delegate` property.

Comment: Thank you for this answer–it answers my question much more in depth and in the right direction. Curious about how Swift handles it, but that might be a question for another time. The other answers are helpful, but were already concepts I was aware of and understood from an implementation standpoint. If you have any suggestions for how I could rephrase my question to make it more clear, please let me know!

Comment: @JimmyHsu Glad I could help. I added some links that should help diving into how Swift handles things.

Comment: Saw those updates, extremely helpful for me to understand what's going on. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You're confused.

Conforming to a protocol is like saying that you speak a language.

A person can speak more than one language. Say I speak English, French, and German. I declare myself as conforming to the English, French, and German protocols.

I can then set myself as the delegate of any object who's delegate needs to conform to one of those protocols.

Think of this as me being a telephone operator. The phone system knows that I speak English, French, and German, so it will route phone calls to me from customers speaking any of those languages.

Self is self. In your example, you're defining the code for the `TextFieldViewController`. You tell the compiler that a `TextFieldViewController` object conforms to both the `UITextFieldDelegate` and  `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocols. That means you speak both of those "languages"

All the compiler does at compile time is to make sure, when you say `someUITextField.delegate = someObject`, that `someObject` is an object that conforms to the protocol the text field needs it to conform to, in this case, `UITextfieldDelegate.`

If you added a `UITableView` to your storyboards and tried to connect your view controller as the table view's delegate without conforming to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol, the compiler would complain because the view controller has not stated the it knows how to serve that role.

Since the `TextFieldViewController` class conform to both the `UITextFieldDelegate` and  `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocols, it can be a delegate to either of those types of objects. It's not uncommon for a view controller to conform to a half-dozen different protocols, and serve as the delegate of a large number of objects.

### EDIT:

You asked:

> What exactly is the compiler doing when I set textField.delegate to
>   self and pickerView.delegate to self? It seems the compiler is smart
>   enough to figure it out, but I'm curious to know what happens behind
>   the scenes

The compiler checks to see what type of object the text field's delegate needs to be. It learns that, for the text field's delegate, it needs to be an object that conforms to the `UITexFieldDelegate` protocol.

It looks at the object on the right side of the equals sign (self), verifies that self, which is an object of type `TextFieldViewController`, conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. Since it does, it installs self into the text field's delegate property.

Then, when the text field needs to send a message to it's delegate, it sends a message to the object stored in the delegate property. The receiving object sends the incoming message to the appropriate method in it's implementation.

Comment: I probably didn't communicate clearly enough that I understood the process, but specifically I'm talking about this:  

"Think of this as me being a telephone operator. The phone system knows that I speak English, French, and German, so it will route phone calls to me from customers speaking any of those languages."  

I was asking specifically how the phone system does the routing, and knows how to differentiate between each language, or in this case how the compiler "verifies that self, which is an object of type TextFieldViewController, conforms to the UITextFieldDelegate protocol".

Comment: I apologize if this was a really bad/dumb question to ask. I'm not sure how I can word it better. I'm trying to format my last comment better, but the comments section is really restricted.

Comment: You can send any message to any object in Swift or Objective-C. If the object doesn't have a method to receive the message, it crashes. Swift uses the list of protocols in the class definition (or in an extension to the class) to check at compile-time that the class conforms to the protocol. At runtime, it just sends the message to the object, and the object handles it. There is a method dispatch table on the object that it uses to figure out which method to call.

Answer (score 0):

**Delegate** is a thing connected with an object, it has different methods which work with this object. These methods can be overridden by you in any class you're using. For this class being able to contain these methods this class must inherit a object **Delegate**.

`.delegate` is a property that must be set if you want to manage your object from code. It can be set via code or storyboard. This property must contain an object of class which inherited from **Delegate** of this property's owner object. So when you type `tratata.delegate = self` - you're setting the self class as object to this property. Since that moment you can manage different views from code.

Delegates also can contain required methods you must to override. And if you see an error "*does no conform to protocol*" - it means you've forgot one of those.

Good luck!